# Excel - Check if Value of Two Columns are new in a List and Passing a new ID to them

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count

Good Morning,

I'm trying to formulate something in Excel that allow us to check if the value of two columns are new in a list, and if so, assign a new ID for them. If it's not, let it **"Blank" or Assign the same ID** that have been assigned before(**Either way would work for me**).

I'm trying to use something with Count.if, but it doesn't fit. As i'm thinking about this for some time, i decided to look for help.

What i want to do is a formula that solves the "Formula" Columns below:

```
Space|Name|*Formula*
  1  | AB |  1
  1  | AB |  1
  1  | AB |  1
  1  | CA |  2
  2  | DD |  3
  2  | EE |  4
  2  | EE |  4
  3  | SS |  5
  3  | SS |  5
  1  | ZZ |  6
  1  | AB |  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sequential Numbering of Groups of Data

In cell `C2` use the following array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2,B2)=1,MAX(C$1:C1)+1,
INDEX(C$1:C1,MATCH(1,(A$1:A1=A2)*(B$1:B1=B2),0)))
```

Then copy `C2` and pastedown from `C3` to the last cell.

If you're satisfied with just numbering each first occurrence then use the following formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2,B2)=1,MAX(C$1:C1)+1,"")
```

Both solutions use the headers i.e. the headers must not be numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind non-sequential numbering, you can just return the index of the first match found as your identifier:

> Copy into C2, then fill down as necessary. The match row stop may need alteration based on how much data you have

```
=MATCH(A2&"#"&B2, A$2:A$100&"#"&B$2:B$100,0)
```

Or as an array formula (only need to place in C2);

```
=MATCH(A2:A11&"#"&B2:B11, A2:A11&"#"&B2:B11,0)
```

Comment: Unfortanelly it must be sequential, as i want to use the ID to SUMUP all the values that i have in Column D, E, F, G and so on using a Sumif in another tab...

What ill do is manually write all IDs in another tab(one to 1000) and sum them up if they have the same id...

Comment: From your code, I've Tried this:

=IF(MATCH(B2&"#"&C2, B$2:B$50000&"#"&C$2:C$50000,0)<>MATCH(B1&"#"&C1, B$2:B$50000&"#"&C$2:C$50000,0),D1+1,D1) 

It worked, but too heavy and slow.... excel even crashed twice...